# check for sqlite3 ... no extconf.rb failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, extconf.rb

**Please do not just close**

I've recently started learning rails and am having trouble with the rails server command when i run it i get the following error message:

```
 C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:in 'require' cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
```

this is followed by 16 from messages (I will add them if asked).

My system is Windows XP, Ruby version 2.0.0p195, Rails Version 4.0.0.

I will gladly provide further info upon request.

All the solutions I've found i have tried and it has not worked.

**Solutions I've tried:**

1) Knapsack solution

2) ruby setup.rb config -- --with-sqlite-include=c:\sqlite-autoconf-3071700

3) ive tried the sqlite-amalgamation download.

4) uninstalling and reinstalling sqlite3, ruby, rails, rubygems, dev tools, etc.

5) running virtual machine with ubuntu 13.04 (rails server command is working as if i said rails new server)

6) and several other command line runs and various downloads.

Its told me many times that its installed sqlite3 version 1.3.7, but I still get the same result.

Please and thank you for your help in advance!!

P.S. Many of the others are based on windows 7 or higher and older versions of ruby and/or rails.

Comment: Did you try RubyInstaller or so?

Comment: @Michael yes and later I tried rails installer I can try rails installer again.